# R: Finding the middle row of a column and returning a value

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I am new to `R`, stackOverflow, and codding in general (hands on learning) so forgive me if I make any mistakes. I have a `data.frame` in `R` as so:

```
Year Location A  Location B   Location C 
1900    NA          1             NA
1901    NA          3             5
1902    3           NA            6
1903    4           NA            4
1902    6           NA            NA
```

I've tried all sorts of approaches with no success, what I need is to identify the middle row in each location column and return the corresponding value from the Year column, for example:

```
Location A   Location B  Location C
    1903          1901        1902
```

In practice the data I will be using will have `n` columns and `n` rows. The aim of extracting this data is to aid in produce a graphical output with the name of each location centered over the graphical line output.

Comment: How do you define the "middle row"?

Comment: For the 3rd column, how did you select 1901, as there are only two non-NA values 1 and 3.

Comment: Are all non-`NA` values consecutive in each row, meaning that there are no `NA`s scattered in between?

Comment: This is currently ill defined. Do you actually mean to say 'median non-null value'? Do you break ties (as in column 2) or return two values? If tie-breaking, what is the mechanism?

Comment: As an example: If there are 7 entries in a column, the middle row would be the one containing the forth entry. With my example above Location C has 3 entries (ignoring NA's) so the middle row contains the second entry corresponding to year 1902.

Comment: Yes, all NA's are together.

Comment: They aren't together in Location C

Comment: the nonNAs are together, that's what counts, IMO

Comment: Sorry by "together" I mean there are no NA's between the entries  only outside.

Comment: Serban, I am not looking for the 'median non-null value', in essence what is actually contained within the rows, as long as they are not NA's, dosn't matter. I am looking for the middle row. I.e. if there are 3 rows the middle row will be the 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
idx <- apply(df,2,function(x)(min(which(!is.na(x))))+floor(length(na.omit(x))/2))[-1]
df2 <- rbind(colnames(df)[-1],df[idx,1])
#> df2
#     [,1]         [,2]         [,3]        
#[1,] "Location.A" "Location.B" "Location.C"
#[2,] "1903"       "1901"       "1902"
```

The first part of the `apply()` function is essentially a wrapper for a loop over all columns of the dataframe `df`. The number 2, as the second parameter, is the so-called margin. It indicates that columns are selected (and not rows, which would be chosen by using the margin 1).

What follows is a function that calculates the relevant row number for each column. The part `min(which(!is.na(x))))` yields the index of the first element in the column (counting from the top) that is not `NA`. Here `x` is a vector containing the column of `df` that is selected by `apply()`. Then the length of the sequence of non-`NA` entries is calculated with `length(na.omit(x))`. This length is divided by two, to obtain the "middle" of the sequence. The function `floor()` ensures that the value is rounded to the next-lowest integer if the result is not an integer. The output of `apply()` is a vector `idx` containing the row index for each column of interest. With the `[-1]` at the end of the line we discard the result for the first column, "Year", which is not important here.

As an example, in "Location C" (column four) we have `min(which(!is.na(df[,4])))` equal to 2. We add to this number `floor(length(na.omit(df[,4]))/2)`, which is equal to `floor(1.5)` and results in `1`. Thus, the value of `idx` of column 4 is 2+1=3.

The second line of the code assembles the resulting matrix `df2` by using the names of the columns of the original dataframe and the entry of the "Year" (column 1) according to the previously calculated row index `idx` for each column of `df`.

Hope this helps.

**data**

```
text <-"Year 'Location A'  'Location B'   'Location C' 
     1900    NA          1             NA
     1901    NA          3             5
     1902    3           NA            6
     1903    4           NA            4
     1902    6           NA            NA"
df <- read.table(text=text, header=T)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, It almost worked, but for Location C it  returned "1903" instead of "1902". It worked perfectly for the other two Locations.

Comment: I have revised the post and now it seems to work. Please let me know if you encounter further difficulties.

Comment: Please, [consider adding an explanation of what the code is actually doing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques).

Answer (score 0):

```
x<-data.frame(Year=c("1900","1901","1902","1903","1902"),
              LocationA=c(NA,NA,3,4,6),
              LocationB=c(1,3,NA,NA,NA),
              LocationC=c(NA,5,6,4,NA))

middle_year <- function(df,column_name)
{
  vec<-na.omit(as.vector(df[[column_name]]))
  if(length(vec) %% 2 == 0)
  {
    vec<-head(vec,n=-1)
  }
  median_val <- median(vec)
  return(df[which(df[,column_name]==median_val),]$Year)
}

> sapply(colnames(x)[-1],middle_year,df=x)
LocationA LocationB LocationC 
     1903      1900      1901 
Levels: 1900 1901 1902 1903
```

Comment: Please, [consider adding an explanation of what the code is actually doing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques).